# Editable vlookup value returned?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I have two pages of spreadsheets in Google Sheets. Sheet1 and Sheet2.
I have a `Vlookup` function in Sheet2 that returning me the value in sheet1.

I would like to know if there is a way to edit this returned value in sheet2 and this value entered in sheet2 be updated in sheet1.

If I try to do that now, it only changes the `vlookup` formula.

Comment: They don't address questions like this in the documentation, since it's not "the answer you'd like to hear," plus it's asked in a reasonable enough way, so I'm not sure why you got down-voted. But the answer's still no, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is simply not possible.

Data can be displayed in many places, or used in many formulas, but if it is "just" a value in a cell, it must have one canonical source.

If this is a serious requirement for your project, consider using a database rather than a spreadsheet. Or research whether or not this sort of dual-direction flow is feasible and advisable via Google Apps Script. Both of those are serious undertakings though, and almost certainly overkill.